# Serialization of an object from external API

Tags: java, serializable

I'm getting the java.io.NotSerializableException.

How can I serialize an object that does not implement `java.io.Serializable`?

I would like to serialize it in a stream.

I want to serialize an object from an external API. I can't modify this API.

In the external API, this object does not implement `java.io.Serializable`

Sure there are private fields, but there are a lot of getter and setter methods.
There are public static fields, and there is not a no-arg constructor, really, there is no constructor.

I think it's difficult to serialize it, isn't it?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

if you can override the external API can create your own class which is a child of the external class.

Your child class can implement Serializable interface and you can serialize your class.

For ex-

ur external class is

```
class ExternalAPIClass
{
..
..
}

Class MyClass extends ExternalAPIClass implements Serializable
{

....
...
...
}
```

Comment: The problem is, this ExternalAPIClass use an object that is not serializable too.

Comment: The problem is, this ExternalAPIClass use an object that is not serializable too. Will I have to override this AnotherEXternalAPIClass too?

Comment: then in that case, the non-serializable parts of your super class should be accessible from you child class(MyClass) and you can write your own methods for custom serialization of those parts. Also, note your super class(ExternalAPIClass) should have a default no argument constructor in that case.


implement writeObject() and readObject() and do manual serialization/deserialization of those non-serializable fields.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you can create new instances of that object, and set their fields through setters. Then I suggest you use the getters to extract all the fields of the object into a Map, and then serialize that map.

Later you deserialize the map, create a new instance of the object, and set all the fields back with the setters.

Of course this is assuming there isn't any read only field that is set at construction time, like an ID. Because in that case the ids would be different.